# Нумерация в Listbox

Tags: python, tkinter

Необходимо прочитать файл с фамилиями и пронумеровать их(согласно кол-во строчек в файле).

Получается нумерация и фамилии отдельно, а как объединить ?

Должно получиться :

```
1. Иванов
2. Петров
3. Сидоров
И Т.Д.
```

```
with open('fio.txt', 'r') as file:
     s = file.readlines()

for item in s:                        
    listbox.insert(END, f"{item}")

for i in range(len(s)):
    listbox.insert(END, f"{i}")
    #listbox.insert(END, f"{item}")
```

Comment: ну так смотри - сначала ты в цикле добавляешь в конец фамилии, а после этого добавляешь в конец числа. А нужно число и фамилию добавлять одновременно за одно действие. И нумерация у тебя идет с нуля.

Answer (score 2):

Есть встроенная функция [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), которая посчитает вам ваши фамилии. И как в комментариях указал Эникейщик, `insert` можно сделать одной операцией:

```
with open('fio.txt', 'r') as file:
     s = file.readlines()

for enum, item in enumerate(s, start=1):                        
    listbox.insert(END, f"{enum}. {item}")
```